# While loop Mysqli doesn't save in array

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using `Class` and `function`, trying to send data from `mysqli while loop` to  `public $post=array();` in `Class`,

I dunno why `while loop` only save last data from `mysqli`

**Code**

```
class Post extends Connection{

        public $post=array();

        function selectPost(){
            $query="select * from posts";
            $mysqli=$this -> connect();
            $select_all_post=$mysqli->query($query);
            $x=1;
            while($row=$select_all_post->fetch_object()){  
                $this->post = array( 'Post No   ' . $x=> array(
                    'post_title' => $row->post_title,
                    'post_author' => $row->post_author,
                    'post_date' => $row->post_date,
                    'post_content' => $row->post_content
                ));
                $x++;
            }
            echo print_r($this->post);
        }
    }
```

if im trying to use [] at post array, it works but it make new array
[Check Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWd5A.png)

```
$this->post[] = array( 'Post No   ' . $x=> array(
                        'post_title' => $row->post_title,
                        'post_author' => $row->post_author,
                        'post_date' => $row->post_date,
                        'post_content' => $row->post_content
                    ));
```

My question, how to send all data from `mysqli` using `while loop` to `array` in `Class`?

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjnwQ.png)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the post number as the array *key* on your class property `$this->post` instead of indexing a new array each time:

```
$this->post['Post No ' . $x] = array(
    'post_title' => $row->post_title,
    'post_author' => $row->post_author,
    'post_date' => $row->post_date,
    'post_content' => $row->post_content
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using **$this->post = array(...**. After your while loop, the last assigned value is the last record of your query.

I'm not sure how you're going to perform your saving on this. I assume that after you have your posts collection, then you will loop on it and that's where you will perform the insertion right?.

Anyhow, considering your code, you can use **array_push**. Like so,

```
array_push($post, array( 'Post No ' . $x=> array(
        'post_title' => $row->post_title,
        'post_author' => $row->post_author,
        'post_date' => $row->post_date,
        'post_content' => $row->post_content
    )));
```

Comment: This is just a slightly longer version of the second part of what he has tried already